# What literal characters should be escaped in a regex?

Tags: php, regex, escaping, pcre

I just wrote a regex for use with the php function `preg_match` that contains the following part:

```
[\w-.]
```

To match any word character, as well as a minus sign and the dot. While it seems to work in preg_match, I tried to put it into a utility called [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/) and it complaints about *"Empty range in char class"*. Trial and error taught me that this issue was solved by escaping the minus sign, turning the regex into

```
[\w\-.]
```

Since the original appears to work in PHP, I am wondering why I should or should not be escaping the minus sign, and - since the dot is also a character with a meaning in PHP - why I would not need to escape the dot. Is the utility I am using just being silly, is it working with another regex dialect or is my regex really incorrect and am I just lucky that preg_match lets me get away with it?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `preg_quote`?

Comment: Probably not. But that's not why I asked the question. I was trying to learn something new about regular expressions, just using `preg_quote` would have the exact opposite effect. :). I do realise I tagged this PHP, but I was looking for an answer that may apply to any PCRE implementation.

Comment: I see. Then, may I suggest: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a3ca6b09cdf1ed904d3e3a56878c1cf6b1a04d1b/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c

Comment: While it still doesn't tell me "directly" what and what not to escape, and why, it does hold all the answers as to how it behaves. For reference, a mirror of the official source: https://github.com/luvit/pcre2/tree/master/src

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In many regex implementations, the following rules apply:

Meta characters inside a character class are:

- `^` (negation)
- `-` (range)
- `]` (end of the class)
- `\` (escape char)

So these should all be escaped. There are some corner cases though:

- `-` needs no escaping if placed at the very start, or end of the class (`[abc-]` or `[-abc]`). In quite a few regex implementations, it also needs no escaping when placed directly after a range (`[a-c-abc]`) or short-hand character class (`[\w-abc]`). This is what you observed
- `^` needs no escaping when it's *not* at the start of the class: `[^a]` means any char except `a`, and `[a^]` matches either `a` or `^`, which equals: `[\^a]`
- `]` needs no escaping if it's the only character in the class: `[]]` matches the char `]`

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thanks. One question about `[]]`: If you have only one character in the class, why not specify it as `\]`? (i.e. not between brackets)

Comment: @Pelle "why not" is another question, irrelevant one. "There is more than one way to do it" is a motto of inventor of preg ;)

Comment: @Pelle, thanks. True, you could (or should?) simply use `\]` instead of a character class, but I wanted to mention that many regex implementations allow `[]]` to match a literal `]`. You don't even need to escape the `]`, since it is only a meta character inside a character class. Outside of it, only `[` needs to be escaped from the two square brackets (but escaping `]` doesn't hurt!).

Comment: The character used to wrap/delimit the RegExp must be escaped, typically '/'.

Comment: @AFAMed, that is a language restriction, not specific to regex itself.

Comment: I totally agree with you, I added this small note because the question is tagged with PHP.

Comment: Since PCRE2 (starting at PHP7.3), an hyphen after a short-hand character class (and before an other character) is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 6):

```
[\w.-]
```

- the `.` usually means any character but between `[]` has no special meaning
- `-` between `[]` indicates a range unless if it's escaped or either first or last character between `[]`

Comment: Does the `.` really mean 'any character' while in a character class? (i.e. between brackets)

Comment: @Pelle that's true. I'm just editing the answer. most of the answers got that wrong ;-)

Answer (score 4):

While there are indeed [some characters should be escaped in a regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), you're asking not about regex but about character class. Where dash symbol being special one.

instead of escaping it you could put it at the end of class, `[\w.-]`

Answer (score 3):

The full stop loses its meta meaning in the character class.

The `-` has special meaning in the character class. If it isn't placed at the start or at the end of the square brackets, it must be escaped. Otherwise it denotes a character range (`A-Z`).

You triggered **another special case** however. `[\w-.]` works because `\w` does not denote a single character. As such PCRE can not possibly create a character range. `\w` is a possibly non-coherent class of symbols, so there is no end-character which could be used to create the range `Z till .`. Also the full stop `.` would preceed the first ascii character `a` that `\w` could match. There is no range constructable. Hencewhy `-` worked without escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php and you need to escape special regex chars, just use `preg_quote`:

An example from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
<?php
// In this example, preg_quote($word) is used to keep the
// asterisks from having special meaning to the regular
// expression.

$textbody = "This book is *very* difficult to find.";
$word = "*very*";
$textbody = preg_replace ("/" . preg_quote($word, '/') . "/",
                          "<i>" . $word . "</i>",
                          $textbody);
?>
```