# Mod Rewrite Pattern Issue

Tags: php, mysql, regex, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What literal characters should be escaped in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484084/what-literal-characters-should-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

```
RewriteRule ^profile/[A-Za-z_-\d\^\.]/*$ ./index.php?page=showuser&username=$1
```

I am new to mod rewrite. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my pattern here? I am trying to only let names passed in that have characters, numbers, -, ^, _ and . symbols but it will give me an error when I use that syntax.

Comment: The error it gives me is "Object not found!". I am working on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 things:

- missing a slash at the start
- you forgot a `+` after your character class :)
- you also forgot to capture the username :p
- you should always put the `-` character in caracter classes at the beginning fo the class

(also, you don't need to escape anything else than `]` inside a character class)

```
RewriteRule ^/profile/([-A-Za-z_\d^.]+)/*$ ./index.php?page=showuser&username=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w\d\.^_-]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=showuser&username=$1
```

It might be better to use

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w\d\.^_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=showuser&username=$1
```

if your index.php file is in the top (root) of your public folder.