# Erasing multiple symbols from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know that `preg_replace('/[{}]/', '', $string);` will erase curly brackets, but what if I had square brackets too and also needed to erase them?

Comment: Add them to character class with proper escaping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include square brackets (escaped) into the character class: `/[{}\[\]]/`

Comment: Not sure you _have_ to escape the opening `[` in a class - but that's just nitpicking

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: good point! It is ok to leave `[` unescaped inside a charclass. As for me, a regex is more readable if both brackets are escaped in the same way (IMHO). [It is always safe to precede a non-alphanumeric with "\" to specify that it stands for itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 3):

Why go through the trouble of using regex for this. If all you're doing is replacing 4 chars from a string:

```
str_replace(array('[',']','{','}'),'',$string);
```

Will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/[{}\[\]]/', '', $string);
```

You should add them with proper escaping to class in Regex

```
 $string = 'asdf{[]a]}ds';
 echo preg_replace('/[{}\[\]]/', '', $string);
```

**Output**: `asdfads`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to escape it:

```
/[{}[\]]/
```

Comment: I wasn't sure but here, for the downvoter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484084/what-literal-characters-should-be-escaped-in-a-regex

Comment: the answer is fully correct; the reason for downvote is mystic... +1

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for a square bracket removal:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\[([^\[\]]++|(?R))*+\]/", "", $str);
```

That will convert this:

```
This [text [more text]] is cool
```

to this:

```
This is cool
```

**EDIT**

```
$string = '<p>hey</p><p>[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"67","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"125","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"125"}}]]</p>';
$new_string = preg_replace('/\[\[.*?\]\]/', '<b>img inserted</b>', $string);

echo $new_string;
```

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: did you forget curly brackets?

Comment: it is working for me.. :) @A.S.Roma Also check my updated answer for more idea