# regular expression not containing two or more consecutive chars

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression which matches a string that starts and ends with a letter and in between it contains 4-8 chars: `A-z`, `-`, `_`, and `.`

String must not contain two or more consecutive `-`, `.` or `_`  chars.

Regex without consecutive restriction is `^[A-z][A-z_\\.\\-]{4,8}[A-z]$` How to add a restriction here or maybe it's not possible?

I know that a prefered way to do negation of specific words in regex is with negative lookahead, but I don't know how to implement it here.

Comment: Do you really want `A-z`?  This not only matches all upper-case and lower-case letters, it matches several characters in between `Z` and `a` on the ASCII chart, specifically `'['`, `'\\'`, `']'`, `'^'`, `'_'` (which you do want), and a back-quote which is hard to type into StackOverflow.  Maybe `A-Za-z`?

Comment: Please choose a specific language. Java and Javascript regex engines work differently.

Comment: @RohitJain Java is the correct language

Comment: @ajb yep, that's what I need, but for the simplicity of the question I put A-z

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead beforehand to check there is not any consecutive character in that character class. Try with this regex:

```
str.matches("(?!.*([._-])\\1)[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z._-]{4,8}[a-zA-Z]");
```

Explanation:

```
 (?!          // Start negative look-ahead (not followed by)
     .*       // Any string
     (        // Start capture group 1
       [._-]  // Any of ., _, -
     )
     \\1       // \1 (escaped \\1) Same character captured in capture group 1 (avoid consecutive)
 )            // Look-ahead ends
 [A-Za-z]     // Alphabets
 [a-zA-Z._-]  // Any of alphabets, ., -, _
 {4,8}        // repeated 4 to 8 times
 [a-zA-Z]     // ends with alphabet
```

Comment: on addition: explanation why escaping is not needed inside character class: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484084/what-literal-characters-should-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use a separate regex to validate that the string doesn't contain the consecutive characters:

```
if(!str.match(/--|\.\.|__/)) {
  // passed the test
}
```

(This is JavaScript syntax, translate to your language of choice!)

Comment: I find this a much preferable solution to a XY problem. It's much more readable than complexifying the other regular expression.