# Remove a list of special characters from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace a string with specific list of special characters to string.Empty.

Example: 123 ~Main To 123 Main

List of Special character :  + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

I know that we can do like this below, can we have better way, using some Regular expressions.

```
> keyword = keyword.Replace("+", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("&&", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("||", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("!", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("(", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace(")", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("{", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("}", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("[", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("]", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("^", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("~", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("*", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("?", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace(":", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
>         keyword = keyword.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected behavior for string `Hello |*| world`? If we first replace `||` and then `*`, we get `Hello || world`, if we do the opposite, we get `Hello world`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build regex on the fly - `\+|&&|\|\||!|\(|\)|\{|}|\[|]|\^|~|\*|\?|:|\\|"`:

```
string input = "Hello world!";
string[] replaceables = new[] { "+", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "\"" };
string rxString = string.Join("|", replaceables.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)));
string output = Regex.Replace(input, rxString, string.Empty);
```

You also can optimize regex as @Robin suggested (though the generation becomes complicated) - `[\+!\(\)\{}\[\]\^~\*\?:\\"]|&&|\|\|`

```
string rxString = string.Join("|", replaceables.GroupBy(r => r.Length > 1)
                                               .Select(g => g.Key ? string.Join("|", g.Select(r => Regex.Escape(r)))
                                                                  : string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(string.Empty, g.Select(r => r == "]" ? "\\]" : Regex.Escape(r))))));
```

Slightly more clean regex (only [metacharacters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484178/1803777) between square brackets are escaped) - `[+!(){}[\]\^~*?:\\"]|&&|\|\|`.

```
string rxString = string.Join("|", replaceables.GroupBy(r => r.Length > 1)
                                               .Select(g => g.Key ? string.Join("|", g.Select(r => Regex.Escape(r)))
                                                                  : string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(string.Empty, g.Select(r => new[] { "]", @"\", "-", "^" }.Contains(r) ? @"\" + r : r)))));
```

The cleanest possible regex (additional validation for requirements to escape metacharacters) - `[+!(){}[\]^~*?:\\"]|&&|\|\|`

```
string rxString = string.Join("|", replaceables.GroupBy(r => r.Length > 1)
                                               .Select(g => g.Key ? string.Join("|", g.Select(r => Regex.Escape(r)))
                                                                  : string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(string.Empty, g.Select((r, i) => r == @"\" || r == "]" && g.Count() > 1 || r == "^" && i == 0 || r == "-" && i > 0 ? @"\" + r : r)))));
```

If you have strings like `Hello &|&&|& complicated world!`, then you need to pass it several times.

```
string output = input;
string outputRef = output;
do
{
    outputRef = output;
    output = Regex.Replace(output, rxString, string.Empty);
} while (output != outputRef);
Console.WriteLine(output); // Hello  complicated world
```

Comment: Just FYI, for performance issue using `[...]` instead of a long `.|...|.` is usually way quicker to match one character pattern.

Comment: @Robin He has multiple character patterns.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Mixing both approaches would be the optimum way to go: something like `[-+!(){}\[\]^\"~*?:\\]|\|\||&&`

Comment: @Robin I added generation function according to your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
        //to remove non alphanumeric characters (special characters) from a string?
        public static string removespclchr(string input)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
            return regex.Replace(input, "");
        }
```

or

```
string q = Regex.Replace(query, @"&quot;|['"",&?%\.*:#/\\-]", " ").Trim();
```

or

```
string replacestr= Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", " ");
```

Comment: Why did you add `_` in the last character class? Also I'm not sure (to clarify with the OP?) that single `|` should be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Another "pretty" solution using LINQ:

```
const string input = "+Hello world!-&&-Hey!";
string[] replaceables = { "+", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "\"" };
var cleanInput = replaceables.Aggregate(input, (result, item) => result.Replace(item, string.Empty));
```

but I guess that using Regex expression would be more effective solution in performance terms (esp. if your strings are large).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` here:

```
string str = "+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \\";
string[] array = str.Split();

string s = "123 ~Main";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in s)
{
    sb = array.Contains(c.ToString()) ? sb.Append("") : sb.Append(c);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // 123 Main
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the replace function so badly, then do it like this:

```
string[] replaceables = new[] { "+", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "\"" };

for(int i = 0; i < replaceables.lenght; i++)
{
  myString = myString.replace(replaceables[i], String.Empty);
}
```

- Array "string[] replaceables" copied from @Ulugbek Umirov