# Exclamation symbol in regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

While using regular expression I found one issue. Can any one please give proper reason for the below scenario's

Scenario-1

```
var regExp=/^[a-zA-Z0-9!-@#$^_:,. ]$/;
regExp.test('<')// True
```

Scenario-2

```
var regExp=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-!@#$^_:,. ]$/;
regExp.test('<')// false
```

There is a change with Exclamation symbol position in regular expression.

Comment: `!-@` is a *range* of characters, which includes `<`. In the second example, the position of the `-` means it's just a `-`. Note you can use things like https://regex101.com/ to test your expressions and get explanations of what they match.

Comment: Could you brief it......

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Badly worded. I should have said it won't work as you expect it to. Your comment covered it better.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484084/what-literal-characters-should-be-escaped-in-a-regex not sure if dupeworthy though..

Answer (score 0):

First Regex

```
var regExp=/^[a-zA-Z0-9!-@#$^_:,. ]$/;
```

`!-@` matches the range of characters. According to the [ASCII](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/AsciiChart.jsp) values it includes `<`

**Reason**

- `a-z` - matches `a` to `z` characters
- `A-Z` - matches `A` to `Z` characters
- `0-9` - matches `0` to `9` characters
- `!-@` matches `!` to `@` characters
- `#$^_:,.` characters will be matched

Second Regex

```
var regExp=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-!@#$^_:,. ]$/;
```

`-` is working as normal `-` character then this regex doesn't match `<`

**Reason**

- `a-z` - matches `a` to `z` characters
- `A-Z` - matches `A` to `Z` characters
- `0-9` - matches `0` to `9` characters
- `-!@#$^_:,.` characters will be matched.

Hope you got it

Comment: It might be helpful to add *why* it's just a `-` in the second case, and how you could make its position unimportant to avoid the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated the answer thanks for advice

Comment: I don't think you've answered jonrsharpe's questions. `9-!` doesn't act as a range in the second regex because the `9` is already part of the `0-9` range. (`9-!` wouldn't be a valid range anyway because `!` is before `9` in ASCII order.) Likewise a `-` at the start or end of a character class is literal, for example in `/[-a]/`, `/[a-]/` or even the negative character class `/[^-a]/`. Personally I dislike this feature. I think it comes from regex's origins in Perl. `\-` in a character class will always match a literal `-`, and I prefer to do it that way.